# $||T-I|| < 1$ implies that $T$ is invertible.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be a banach space and $T : B \to B$ be a bounded linear transformation.

If for identity transformation $I : B \to B$ , $||T-I||$<1 , then $T$ is invertible.

|| || is norm of transformation.

Comment: let $S = I-T$ then $\|S\| < 1$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty S^k$ converges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S=I-T$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n S^k$. Then $$(I-S)S_n = I - S^{n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow I $$ since $\|S\|<1$, so the operator $$S_\infty := \sum_{k=0}^\infty S^k $$ is bounded. Moreover, $(I-S)S_\infty=S_\infty(I-S)=I$, so it follows that $S_\infty=(I-S)^{-1}$. Since $T=I-S$, we conclude that $T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier: Suppose you had a nonzero $x$ with $Tx=0$. What does this tell you about $\|T-I\|$?

Comment: What about surjectivity?

Comment: Ah, good point. I was not thinking about the infinite-dimensional situation.